# Parse XML columns from SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server

In have a SpecialPurposeColumn in a table with no data. When i do select * from tablename, it displays only one column named SpecialPurposeColumn. But in SQL Server DB > Tables i can see all the columns. While loading data to this table, the loading fails because it recognize as only one column. Actually this column is created as XML Column_Set.

How can i parse the column names out of this one XML column? Below screenshot is what i see when i do select * from the tablname. But actually there are many columns like Id, Firstname, lastname etc inside it. I can view that by opening the DB but not querying

Thanks,
Arun

[image]

[image]

[image]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Bear_tgt](  A varchar SPARSE  NULL,B varchar SPARSE  NULL,C varchar SPARSE  NULL,D varchar SPARSE  NULL,E] varchar SPARSE  NULL,[SpecialPurposeColumns] [xml] COLUMN_SET FOR ALL_SPARSE_COLUMNS  NULL)

Selecting all the columns and insert into.

Comment: It might help to include your `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements, and an example of current and desired output, so we can see what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Edited the question. Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you include a screen dump of "view that by opening the DB"

Comment: Edited the question. All columns are SPARSE NULL with the last column being SpecialPurposeColumns

Comment: @IMSoP this is how i create the table (edited the question)